# Does the NSManagedObject instance still float around in space when it turns into a fault?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Or is turning into a fault the same as deleting that thing completely? I mean... is that guy then just still alive as a super lightweight object with no big data inside, or is it actually deleted?

Or: Is a fault an object in memory with low footprint, or is that a "virtual object that COULD be there, but isn't yet"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, definitely it's not the same thing as deleting the object. Moreover, there is no guarantee that it will be flushed back to the filesystem nor there is a guarantee that it will be removed from the cache. For instance, assuming the object has no changes, nothing needs to be written on the filesystem, and there is a chance that, instead, it will remain in cache.